# Html attribute containing empty string doesn't show = operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One use case is in jQuery:

```
 $select.append('<option value="">All</option>');
```

It looks like it actually adds the element in HTML:

```
<option value>All</option>
```

Instead, what I want is to append to the element so that it gives an empty string to value:

```
<option value="">All</option>
```

Why doesn't that happen?

Comment: What makes you think there's a difference between `value=""` and `value`? They both represent no value being set.

Comment: It's a behavior from the browser, no need to output empty properties

Comment: And to expand on what @sphanley wrote, an elements value is always a string, and no value being set will always return an empty string.

Comment: @sphanley even if the `=""` is in the source code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It actually add the element in HTML

No, it doesn't.

It adds the element to the DOM, not to the HTML.

When you look at the DOM, using your browser's developer tools, it will displayed using HTML-like syntax. In this syntax, a `value` attribute where the value is an empty string will be rendered without the `=""` portion. (It is looking like that part of the syntax is actually valid HTML, but I haven't found the part in the spec which allows it.)

If you were (to use Chrome as an example), you could right click on its parent element and pick "Edit as HTML" at which point you would see the `=""` again.

---

If you were to submit the form containing the select element you would see that the data sent would be: `select_name=`. This shows that the value was correctly set to an empty string. If it had not worked you would have got `select_name=All` since the element's text is used as the value if no value is set.

Comment: Technically, though, `value` without the `=""` is totally valid HTML syntax. There's no reason that the raw HTML needs to show the `=""` unless you're using an XHTML format.

Comment: +1 "*the element's text is used as the value if no value is set*" is spot on. If you do not specify that the value is `""` then `All` will be the value.

Comment: @sphanley — The validator seems to agree. I'm trying to find where in the spec it allows it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to indicate a degree of confusion as to the meaning of the syntax in question. Based on the fact that the occurrence of `value` in your tag lacks a `=""`, you're inferring that this represents an HTML "value" element - that's not the case. What's actually happening here has to do with the fact that there's multiple ways in which the value of an HTML attribute can be represented. Let's explore those formats, to better understand what you're seeing.

**Valid formats for HTML Attributes**

---

The most common way you'd represent, say, a `value` attribute would be with quotes, as follows:

```
value="something"
```

However, if you look at [the section of the HTML5 spec regarding attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0), it's actually also valid to represent attribute values in four different ways:

> - empty attribute syntax
> - unquoted attribute-value syntax
> - single-quoted attribute-value syntax
> - double-quoted attribute-value syntax

The format that specifically speaks to your case is "empty attribute syntax". Reading further, the spec describes the Empty Attribute syntax as follows:

> Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.

There's also a slightly more detailed explanation on the [historical HTML 5 reference for attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes):

> Certain attributes may be specified by providing just the attribute
>   name, with no value.
>
> In the following example, the disabled attribute is given with the
>   empty attribute syntax:
>
> `<input disabled>`
>
> Note that empty syntax is exactly equivalent to specifying the empty
>   string as the value for the attribute, as in the following example.
>
> `<input disabled="">`

As you're seeing, this means that for an HTML element, when representing a property with no value, the `=""` is optional. As such, some browsers will just display the property without that unnecessary markup. Whether the property is rendered as `value` or `value=""`, any standards compliant browser will know that `value` is a property which holds a string, so it will therefore always return either that property's contents, if any, or at minimum an empty string in absence of explicit contents.

Comment: Attribute minimization is an SGML term where an attribute that can only hold a set of predefined values (such as `checked` which can only have the value `checked`) can omit the attribute name and the `=`. HTML 5 has a similar rule for boolean attributes, but I didn't think it applied generically (the validator seems to think it does, but I haven't found the applicable bit of spec yet).

Comment: If you follow the link to the XHTML spec that's in my answer, it seems to use "attribute minimization" to refer to cases where an empty attribute is represented without an equal sign or quotes. I'll read a bit further, though, and try to see if I'm misunderstanding this.

Comment: The examples in that case show it is where the name and the value of the attribute are the same string. Not where the value is an empty string.

Comment: Ahah - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes says that "Note that empty attribute syntax is exactly equivalent to specifying the empty string as the value for the attribute, as in the following example." I'm going to have to rewrite this answer to refer to the correct spec.

Comment: Yeah, I think its a new rule in HTML 5. That isn't the spec though. It's a non-normative and discontinued reference.

Comment: Where's the correct HTML5 spec then? I'm confident the same behavior will be described there.

Comment: http://w3.org/TR/html5/ — I'm confident it is too, it's just finding it that's tough. The spec is aimed more at browser implementors.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0 says that "Empty attribute syntax" is "Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string."

Answer (score -1):

```
 $select.append($('<option>', { value: "", text: "All" }));
```

Comment: While this is another possible way to append an `<option>` with an empty value property, it has no explanation, behaves the exact same way as the way that the OP posted and in no way solves or addresses the (non) problem that's being asked about here.