# For loop with javascript add alt to images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript. I am trying to loop throw all images and check if there is an alt property and add empty alt="" to images that don't have one.

```js
var images =document.querySelectorAll(".view.view-mt-latest-news.view-id-mt_latest_news.view-display-id-block_4 > div > div > div > div > a > img  "); 
for (var i = 0, image; image = images[i]; i++) {
  image.alt = "";
}
```

```html
    <div class="view view-mt-latest-news view-id-mt_latest_news view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-16ee052fc9069895592eb40c1695ac6f jquery-once-2-processed">

    <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75" alt="This is alt"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code adds alt to all images like this:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75" alt>
```

It should be like this:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75" alt="">
```

Can anyone help with this for loop.

Comment: What the matter if it's `alt` or `alt=""` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html attribute containing empty string doesn't show = operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117474/html-attribute-containing-empty-string-doesnt-show-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the alt of the image is "" (even if it doesn't appear on the HTML code), but if you want to appear in the HTML code you should do something like this:

```js
    var images =document.querySelectorAll(".view.view-mt-latest-news.view-id-mt_latest_news.view-display-id-block_4 > div > div > div > div > a > img  "); 
    for (var i = 0, image; image = images[i]; i++) {
      if (image.alt == ""){
          image.alt = '\u00A0';
      }
    }
```

'\u00A0' is the unicode for a non breaking space

Answer (score 0):

```js
var images =document.querySelectorAll(".view.view-mt-latest-news.view-id-mt_latest_news.view-display-id-block_4 > div > div > div > div > a > img  "); 
for (var i = 0, image; image = images[i]; i++) {
  image.alt = " ";
}
```

```html
  <div class="view view-mt-latest-news view-id-mt_latest_news view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-16ee052fc9069895592eb40c1695ac6f jquery-once-2-processed">

    <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75" alt="This is alt"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add a space in between ""
your code `image.alt = "";`
shoud be `image.alt = " ";`

```
var images =document.querySelectorAll(".view.view-mt-latest-news.view-id-mt_latest_news.view-display-id-block_4 > div > div > div > div > a > img  "); 
for (var i = 0, image; image = images[i]; i++) {
 image.alt = " ";
}
```

Comment: thank you, now my alt is overridden with empty alt. How can add if statement in order to check if there is alt

Comment: hope this helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735820/find-if-a-img-have-alt-in-jquery-if-not-then-add-from-array

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that browsers will replace html atributes nothing if there value is empty. So place somting as value like a space. Else it's not posible.

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=" ">

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt>
```

Answer (score 0):

The alt attribute provides the text equivalent (alternative) for an image. In other words, it should convey the same information as the image does (in that context).

If you exclude a complete alt tag, visually impaired users will be unable to know that you have a picture in that placement.

```js
var images =document.querySelectorAll(".view.view-mt-latest-news.view-id-mt_latest_news.view-display-id-block_4 > div > div > div > div > a > img  "); 
for (var i = 0, image; image = images[i]; i++) {
if(image.alt){
//do your task
  console.log("alt present with value", image.alt);
}else {
 image.alt = " "; //added one space, there should be something 
//for alt other it will not have any value
}
 
}
```

```html
<div class="view view-mt-latest-news view-id-mt_latest_news view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-16ee052fc9069895592eb40c1695ac6f jquery-once-2-processed">

    <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75" alt="This is alt"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89" height="75"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, now my alt is overridden with empty alt. How can add if statement in order to check if there is alt

Comment: @MijoN  I have added this too in above snippet. Just check with if condition and do your stuff

Answer (score 0):

Alt attribute is using mainly for conveying the message to end user. Also, it will display when image is not loaded. Here you need to check first whether alt tag is there or not. If not there, then you need to add.

```
    <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89"
                            height="75"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89"
                            height="75" alt="This is alt"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first clearfix">
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
                <div class="field-content overlayed">
                    <a href="#"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="89"
                            height="75"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



    var images = document.querySelectorAll(".view-content img "); // Avoid deep level selector

    for (var i = 0, image; image = images[i]; i++) {
        if (!image.getAttribute("alt")) { // Here you need to check whether attribute already present or not.
            image.alt = '';
        }
    }
```

PS: Also, do not use deep level selector and it will affect the performance.